# Настройка файлового сервера на golang

Tags: файлы, golang, download

Здравствуйте. Помогите разобраться с настройками файлового сервера.
Проблема состоит в следующем, имею стандартный сервер:

```
func main() {
   http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files")))
   http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}
```

Имею клиента, для загрузки файла использую такую функцию:

```
func download(filename string){
  out, err := os.Create(filename)
  defer out.Close()
  ...
  resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:5000/"+filename)
  defer resp.Body.Close()
  ...
  n, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
}
```

так вот если запустить на скачку одновременно несколько больших файлов:

```
func main{
  go download("big_file1.avi")
  go download("big_file2.mkv")
  go download("big_file3.avi")
}
```

то скачиваться будут только два файла, третий файл начнёт качаться только после завершения загрузки одного из первый.
Собственно вопрос, как это исправить?

P.S. смотрел на параметр в Транспорте: maxidleconnsperhost, но как то это не помогло.

Comment: Вы уверены, что дело не в том, что у клиента только два ядра?

Comment: Тестировал HTTP File Server (hfs 2.3k) на нём всё работает, то есть причина всё же в настройках файлового сервера на golang.

Comment: @Алексей вы уже нашли решение?

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит потому что в gomaxprocs выставлено значение 2